# how can I add custom shapes to mxgraph

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

How can I add mxgraph custom shapes?

**Shapes as image**

[bpm shapes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGEfj.png)

Comment: Do you use the grapheditor template?

Comment: Actually, I didn't use template...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**// CollateShape**

```
function CollateShape()
{
    mxEllipse.call(this);
};
mxUtils.extend(CollateShape, mxEllipse);
CollateShape.prototype.paintVertexShape = function(c, x, y, w, h)
{
    c.begin();
    c.moveTo(x, y);
    c.lineTo(x + w, y);
    c.lineTo(x + w / 2, y + h / 2);
    c.close();
    c.fillAndStroke();

    c.begin();
    c.moveTo(x, y + h);
    c.lineTo(x + w, y + h);
    c.lineTo(x + w / 2, y + h / 2);
    c.close();
    c.fillAndStroke();
};

mxCellRenderer.registerShape('collate', CollateShape);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add new shapes by creating a new sidebar palette or adding the custom shapes to a existing one

Here's a example:

Let's say you want to add new shapes to the **Basic** palette, go to your **Sidebar.js** and find the function `Sidebar.prototype.addBasicPalette`, here you can add wherever shape you want:

```
/**
 * Adds the general palette to the sidebar.
 */
Sidebar.prototype.addBasicPalette = function(dir)
{
    this.addStencilPalette('basic', mxResources.get('basic'), dir + '/basic.xml',
        ';whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;fillColor=#ffffff;strokeColor=#000000;strokeWidth=2',
        null, null, null, null, [
            this.createVertexTemplateEntry('shape=partialRectangle;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;top=0;bottom=0;fillColor=none;', 120, 60, '', 'Partial Rectangle'),
            this.createVertexTemplateEntry('shape=partialRectangle;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;right=0;top=0;bottom=0;fillColor=none;routingCenterX=-0.5;', 120, 60, '', 'Partial Rectangle'),
            this.createVertexTemplateEntry('shape=partialRectangle;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;bottom=0;right=0;fillColor=none;', 120, 60, '', 'Partial Rectangle'),
            this.createVertexTemplateEntry('shape=partialRectangle;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;top=0;left=0;fillColor=none;', 120, 60, '', 'Partial Rectangle'),
            this.createEdgeTemplateEntry('html=1;verticalAlign=bottom;endArrow=block;', 80, 0, 'is_a', 'Is_A', null, 'uml sequence message call invoke dispatch'),
           // on the line above i created a new arrow with 'is_a' on the top

    ]);
};
```

Comment: Is there a way to inject a new Palette when you load a custom plugin? I have tried just setting up a palette like above and invoking it in my plugin but doesn't seem to fire and add it to the sidebar. This would allow a plugin to be bound to a set of shapes.

Comment: What do you mean by 'custom plugin'? ' You can have any palettes you want, but you need to call this function in the beginning of the file too.

Comment: I tried invoking this via the plugin structure and it doesn't seem to invoke and move create the shapes on the Sidebar. By custom plugin, I mean this - https://desk.draw.io/support/solutions/articles/16000056430-what-plugins-are-available-

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't have any experience with draw.io. I work only with mxgraph, i know that draw.io is build around mxgraph but i think the structure is kinda different. Maybe you can post a question here on this tag so i (or others) can help you out